# Running ClojureScript/Quil on an Ubuntu Server

Tags: java, ubuntu, clojure, clojurescript, quil

I develop on an Ubuntu server without graphics capabilities and view there served website from another computer.

When compiling to ClojureScript I get a `core.clj HeadlessException` on the bare-bones draw function.

I’d like to keep the server as it is. Is this possible? If not, does anybody know what graphics package I would need to grab for Java to work with?

Thanks!

Updated with the error:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.awt.HeadlessException, compiling:(visualizer.cljs:38:1)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval (Compiler.java:3628)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval (Compiler.java:439)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6787)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7227)
    user$eval1902.invoke (form-init1559961897338794738.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6782)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6745)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3081)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099$fn__7102.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__7108.invoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__623.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:58)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:630)
    clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1868)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__665$fn__668.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:191)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__660.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:159)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: null
 at java.applet.Applet.<init> (Applet.java:67)
    processing.core.PApplet.<init> (PApplet.java:159)
    quil.Applet.<init> (:-1)
    quil.applet$applet.doInvoke (applet.clj:448)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval (Compiler.java:3623)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval (Compiler.java:439)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6787)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7227)
    user$eval1902.invoke (form-init1559961897338794738.clj:1)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6782)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6745)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3081)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099$fn__7102.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7099.invoke (main.clj:240)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__7108.invoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:258)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__623.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:58)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:152)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:630)
    clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke (core.clj:1868)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__665$fn__668.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:191)
    clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__660.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:159)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems like you're not using the CLJS version of quil. Did you follow https://github.com/quil/quil/wiki/ClojureScript ?

Comment: @skrat - Thanks for the link. When I ran the basic example, I realized it wasn't a graphics issue but it was indeed a version-related issue. Once I got my ClojureScript version in line, I realized my Clojure version was also incorrect (1.6.0 vs. 1.7.0). Double whammy! 

Since your hunch was right, if you'd like to answer this question, I can give you credit.

Comment: Actually, that was only one issue. The hello-quil still does not work in the repl. It does compile. Therefore, I still believe that I need a graphics driver for Java to interface with. I'm new to Java + Ubuntu, so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Paste the error then, but Java alone, and Clojure(Script) specifically, don't need any graphics driver (100% sure here, because I use them on headless server). Can you upload your project to github repo?

Comment: @skrat - Here is the file that's giving me the error: https://github.com/schmudde/schmud-de/blob/master/src/schmud_de/visualizer.cljs